# How do I fecth and set value from database to my entity field in the edit form (Symfony2)?

Tags: symfony

I am devolping an application in Symfony 2.7, I generated the CRUD from a PRODUCT TABLE (InProducto) which is related OneToMany to another table (InUnidadMedida).
When I open Edit Form, the value in ENTITY FIELD (which is a select field from UNIDAD DE MEDIDA table) always appears the first option of related table (UNIDAD DE MEDIDA). And It suppose to get the value in the field of the table INPRODUCTO

InProductoType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nombre')
            ->add('descripcion')
            ->add('unidadMedida', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'NivalInventarioBundle:InUnidadMedida',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.nombre', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'nombre',
                'by_reference' => false,
                'property' => 'type',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false
            ))
}
```

Controller:

```
private function createEditForm(InProducto $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new InProductoType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('inproducto_update', array('id' => $entity->getIdProducto())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Guardar'));

        return $form;
    }
```

Producto table (Entity)

```
 /**
 * InProducto
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="in_producto")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class InProducto
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InSubLinea", inversedBy="InProducto")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_sub_linea", referencedColumnName="id_sub_linea")
     */
    protected $subLinea;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InUnidadMedida", inversedBy="InProducto")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_unidad_medida", referencedColumnName="id_unidad_medida")
     */
    protected $unidadMedida;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_producto", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
```

Unidad de medida TABLE (entity)

```
 /**
 * InUnidadMedida
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="in_unidad_medida")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class InUnidadMedida
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InProducto", mappedBy="InUnidadMedida")
     */
    protected $InProducto;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->InProducto = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of scratching head, it was very simple, I add the following properties to my fields:

```
        'by_reference' => true,
        'mapped' => true,
```

Thanks Dmitry Malyshenko for your time.

Comment: It's quite strange. They have to make these values by default. It must be something in the code that redefines it.

Answer (score 0):

The form type will be guessed automatically by Symfony, if you've mapped these entities correctly.

So make it just

```
       ->add('unidadMedida', null, array(
            'choice_label' => 'nombre',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false
        ))
```

And there is no such option as `property`. Did you mean `property_path`?

Comment: I tried the code, but when I click on Edit Button and opens form to edit the product, still appears empty the unidadMedida field. Yes, property option it's a mistake.

Comment: Please provide then your doctrine mappings between InUnidadMedida and InProducto

Comment: I added the information requested Dmitry Malyshenko

Comment: Everything's looking fine now. The choices list is OK? Are you sure that for $entity->unidadMedida not null? Make dump($entity) before return $form;

Comment: Is a very long file... my web browser crashed, this is part or the var_dump: "nival_inventariobundle_inproducto_unidadMedida" ["name"]=> string(12) "unidadMedida"

Comment: I've just tried a code and works. It must be some stupid minor error

Comment: I added 'mapped' => true, and I can add new productos, but when I tried to edit, i got this error message: "Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?" I think its trying to map the field.

Comment: Do you have a setter and getter for a property?

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, al already answered the question.But I have a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428090/how-do-i-get-the-field-name-of-my-id-field-related-from-manytoone-relationship