# How do I get the field name of my id field related from ManyToOne relationship?

Tags: symfony

I have 2 tables related, InProducto and InUnidadMedida, which InProducto is related ManyToOne with InUnidadMedida.
I want to know how can I get the name of my related ID to show it in the list.

Index twig

```
        {% for entity in entities %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ entity.idProducto }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.idUnidadMedida }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.costoPromedio }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.idSubLinea }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.idTipoProducto }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.precio1 }}</td>
                <td>
                    {% if entity.inventariable == 0 %}
                        No
                    {% elseif entity.inventariable == 1 %}
                        Sí
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {% if entity.facturable == 0 %}
                        No
                    {% elseif entity.facturable == 1 %}
                        Sí
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {% if entity.activo == 0 %}
                        No
                    {% elseif entity.activo == 1 %}
                        Sí
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
                <td class = "actions">
                    <a href="{{ path('inproducto_show', { 'id': entity.idProducto }) }}" class = "btn btn-sm btn-info">ver</a>
                    <a href="{{ path('inproducto_edit', { 'id': entity.idProducto }) }}" class = "btn btn-sm btn-primary">editar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Where {{ entity.idSubLinea }} and {{ entity.idUnidadMedida }} are the related fields and I want to display the names of each category.

Currently it prints the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just `{{ entity.unidadMedida.name }}` (given the property is `$name`)

You can also make it a bit simpler by making just `{{ entity.unidadMedida }}` and making a method `__toString` in `InUnidadMedida` Entity

```
...
public function __toString() 
{
   return $this->name;
}
...
```

Comment: Awesome! Solved my issue.